# Is it possible to "push up" the entire app when keyboard appear?

Tags: ios, swift

Currently, I have a `UICollectionView`, which multiple rows of `UITextField`.

When the bottom `UITextField`, keyboard will block its visibility.

To make `UICollectionView` still scrollable to bottom, many techniques have been intoriduced

- [How do I scroll the UIScrollView when the keyboard appears?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161666/how-do-i-scroll-the-uiscrollview-when-the-keyboard-appears)
- [How can I make a UITextField move up when the keyboard is present - on starting to edit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-can-i-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-the-keyboard-is-present-on-starting?rq=1)
- Third party library https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

---

Most solution ideas are

1. Calculate the high of keyboard.
2. Adjust the `contentInset` and `scrollIndicatorInsets` of `UICollectionView`

However, such solution doesn't work very well, if my screen is consists of a `UICollectionView` and a bottom `UIView`.

---

### When keyboard is hidden

```
--------------------
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
| UICollectionView |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
--------------------
|                  |
|  Custom UIView   |
|                  |
--------------------
```

---

### When keyboard is shown (My expectation)

```
--------------------
|                  |
|                  |
| UICollectionView |
|                  |
|                  |
--------------------
|                  |
|  Custom UIView   |
|                  |
-------------------- 
|                  |
|                  |
|  Keyboard        |
|                  |
--------------------
```

---

However, current provided solution, is only able to "push up" `UIScrollView`/ `UICollectionView`.

I tend to "push up" entire main `UIView`. Unfortunately, `UIView` doesn't have `contentInset` for me to act upon, based on keyboard height.

This is my current outcome using https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager. The outcome is the same, if I apply solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/32353069/72437

---

### When keyboard is hidden

[image]

---

### When keyboard is shown. Only UICollectionView is being pushed up. The bottom `UIView` will be "covered"

[image]

---

Any idea how I can "push up" entire app screen, instead of just `UICollectionView`/ `UIScrollView`?

Comment: Yes, it is possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070242/move-view-with-keyboard-using-swift

Comment: You don't even need to handle the inset, just calculate the keyboard height, then change the constant of the bottomMostView-to-superView constraint, then whole view will push up.

Comment: I would consider a [solution that adjusts the safeAreaLayoutGuide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45399178/extend-ios-11-safe-area-to-include-the-keyboard) so that it works across all devices.

Comment: @Wez Thanks for the pointer. I will look at them as well. In fact, I think this should be the responsible of OS, to ensure keyboard doesn't cover up the app. It shouldn't require all the ugly manual handling from app developers. 1 trillion dollar company should know this better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most popular answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31124676/72437) is adjusting the Y of the view.

However, that is a **wrong** solution, if one of the UI component inside the view is `UICollectionView`. You will not able to scroll till the start of the list, after you adjust Y of the view.

**The correct solution should be adjusting the height of the view.**

```
private var originalSize: CGSize?

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.originalSize == nil {
            let originalSize = self.view.frame.size
            self.originalSize = originalSize
            self.view.frame.size = CGSize(
                width: originalSize.width,
                height: originalSize.height - keyboardSize.height
            )
        }
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let originalSize = self.originalSize {
        self.view.frame.size = originalSize
        self.originalSize = nil
    }
}
```