# UIViewController + NSNotification extension protocol based @objc issue

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, nsnotifications, swift-extensions

I use this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45399178/extend-ios-11-safe-area-to-include-the-keyboard) to avoid keyboard frame when it appears. Now I want to make it protocol based to avoid extending all view controllers with this functionality. Now I am getting two errors which looks like conflict each other (one is want to add @objc and another one remove it):

[image]

My Code:

```
import UIKit

protocol KeyboardFrameIgnorable {
    func listenForKeyboardFrameChange()
    func stopListenKeyboardFrameChange()
}

extension KeyboardFrameIgnorable where Self: UIViewController {
    func listenForKeyboardFrameChange()
    {
        NotificationCenter.default
            .addObserver(self,
                         selector: #selector(onKeyboardFrameWillChangeNotificationReceived(_:)),
                         name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification,
                         object: nil)
    }

    func stopListenKeyboardFrameChange()
    {
        NotificationCenter.default
            .removeObserver(self,
                            name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification,
                            object: nil)
    }

    @objc
    private func onKeyboardFrameWillChangeNotificationReceived(_ notification: Notification)
    {
        guard
            let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
            let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
        else {
            return
        }

        let keyboardFrameInView = view.convert(keyboardFrame, from: nil)
        let safeAreaFrame = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: -additionalSafeAreaInsets.bottom)
        let intersection = safeAreaFrame.intersection(keyboardFrameInView)

        let keyboardAnimationDuration = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]
        let animationDuration: TimeInterval = (keyboardAnimationDuration as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue ?? 0
        let animationCurveRawNSN = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
        let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSN?.uintValue ?? UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut.rawValue
        let animationCurve = UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration,
                       delay: 0,
                       options: animationCurve,
                       animations: {
            self.additionalSafeAreaInsets.bottom = intersection.height + 10
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: out of curiosity, did you try by doing ‘ protocol KeyboardFrameIgnorable:class’ ?

Comment: @LucaIaco yea same result

Comment: @MatrosovOleksandr Did you find any solution to this?